# Mongoose - finding in subdocument by criteria

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I've just got stuck with this problem. I've got two Mongoose schemas:

```
let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            username: { type:String, default:null },
            email: { type:String, required:true },
            role: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Role', required: true }, 
        });

let roleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: { type:String, default:"Player" },
        privileges:
            [
                {
                    resource: String ,
                    actions: [ String ]
                },
            ],

    });
```

Question si how to find users with specific criteria for exemple Get All Users with Role Name = "super Admin" I try this by no result

```
User.find({'role.name':'Super Admin'}).populate('role')
    .exec()
    .then(results => {
        res.success(results);
    }, error => {
        res.error(error);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give all the users with the desired schema:

```
db.roleSchema.aggregate([
    {$match:{name:'Super Admin'},
    {$lookup: {from: "userSchema",localField: "_id",foreignField: "role",as: "userSchema"}},
    {$unwind : "$userSchema"},
    {$group:{
          _id:'$users._id',
          username:{$first:'$users.username'},
          email:{$first:'$users.email'}
    }}
])
```

Hope my answer was helpful

Comment: the returned value is always null

Comment: Is the role name in the {$match:{name: XXXX}} correct?